# include today's date with expired times

Tags: list

Overview:

- current time 10:00PM
- event_start_date - is a date field
- trying to display all entries from today and all future entries
- i understand >={current_time} includes the time as well but start_on='today' doesn't seem to include entirety of today

Issue:

- It excludes entries that are past the current time and doesn't
- how do you include all entries from the start of today.

List

- 2016-02-08
- 2016-03-01
- 2016-03-29
- 2016-05-02
- 2016-05-15
- 2016-05-17 (9:50 PM)
- 2016-05-18
- 2016-05-18
- 2016-05-30
- 2016-09-12
- 2016-10-24
- 2016-11-01
- 2016-12-06

Code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" search:event_start_date=">={current_time}"
    {event_start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding date format information to the time entries.  Something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" search:{event_start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}=">={current_time format='%Y-%m-%d'}"}
    {event_start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The documentation is not clear on how these comparisons are made, but reading across from [how comparisons of relative dates are handled](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/templates/date_variable_formatting.html) suggests that adding format to the date should (or could) work.  Worth a try I think.

HTH